# How to lock down MySites but leave Profile Page visible to all?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Our company would like to have My Sites in SharePoint 2007 to start off completely locked down to just that user with the expeption of the public Profile page (person.aspx) which they want visible to the entire company.  Does anyone know if this is possible and if so how to configure SharePoint to support this?

Answer (score 1):

http://vivekthangaswamy.blogspot.com/2007/03/remove-or-disable-mysite-in-moss-2007.html

Comment: This article is good but does not actually address my issue.  I want people to use My Sites and am not trying to keep them from creating or using them.  What I don't like however is that the group "NTAuthority\Authenticated Users" is by default in the Readers group because the user doesn't realize when they create new lists or libraries on their site that the entire world can get to it.

So...how to remove this group BUT still retain the ability for everyone to see that person's public profile page?